# Flat file schema for BizTalk with several repeating and optional records

Tags: biztalk, xsd-validation, flat-file

Problem: I receive a complex flat file of which I cannot change the structure.
It looks like the following example (although the original one is far more complex):

```
VER123456
TA_ExampleContent
REFExampleReference
FRAExampleContent
REFExampleReference
AUFExampleContent
REFExampleReference
LS_ExampleContent
REFExampleReference
```

Every record consists of a tag and the data. It is possible that the same tag can be used on different levels of the data structure, e.g. REF. It is used for TA_, FRA, AUF and LS_. The example above gives the impression that all tags are on the same level, but they are not. The structure is like the following:

```
VER123456
   TA_ExampleContent
      REFExampleReference
      FRAExampleContent
         REFExampleReference
         AUFExampleContent
            REFExampleReference
            LS_ExampleContent
               REFExampleReference
```

When I use a sequence or a choice group the data will be on the same level in the output .xml file.

For example the REF records have a configured minimum occurrence of 0 and maximum occurrence of unbounded. As long as at least one REF record exists the validation is successful. If there is no REF record, which is a valid option, the .xsd validation fails with the message "The element xyz has incomplete content."

What I'd like to have:
A description on how to create a schema that can handle such a complex flat file like the one above. Also I am looking for a proper way to deal with optional records.

```
<VER>
   <TA_>
      <Field01></Field01>
      <Field02></Field02>
      <FRA>
         <Field01></Field01>
         <Field02></Field02>
         <REF>
            <Field01></Field01>
            <Field02></Field02>
         </REF>
         <REF>
            <Field01></Field01>
            <Field02></Field02>
         </REF>
         <AUF>
            <Field01></Field01>
            <Field02></Field02>
            <REF> -- could be not available
               <Field01></Field01>
               <Field02></Field02>
            </REF>
            <LS_>
               <Field01></Field01>
               <Field02></Field02>
               <REF>
                  <Field01></Field01>
                  <Field02></Field02>
               </REF>
            </LS_>
         </AUF>
      </FRA>
      <REF>
          <Field01></Field01>
          <Field02></Field02>
      </REF>
   </TA_>
</VER>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it doesn't seem that complicated at all.

Provided there is no ambiguity in the TA_, FRA, AUF and LS_ structure, you have a basic structured flat file.

The key when running the Flat File Wizard, you select an entire Loop, TA_, FRA, AUF, LS_ plus all their descendants as a Repeating Element.

Then the Wizard will circle back and let you further define the loop itself.

In this case, The Wizard should loop back at least 4 time, one for each of TA_, FRA, AUF and LS_, then for each record, like REF.

Run the Wizard as many times as you need to get it right.  There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Hi @Johns-305, thanks for your reply. I already used the wizard, but one of the problems is the validation of the optional records when they don't exist. I addded more code and explanations in the question above. Regards

Comment: @hat The first think I would look at is Group Order Type.  The thing is, you're at the point where you just have to tweak the schema to match the input.  Also, check the Parser Optimization option.

Comment: The record node is a child record with group order type = sequence. also I switched the parser optimization option to complex, but the error still occurs. Also I changed the child record node to a squence/choice group, the problem stll occurs.

Comment: @hat first thing that comes to mind is the use of Tag Identifiers. Second thing: could you provide a few sample messages to work with so we can run it through easily.